# How to change value of global environment variable in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am using a gitlab for my project where I am defining an environment variable inside "Settings->CI/CD->Environment variables" and initializing value of it as "0". Now as part of CI pipeline, I want to modify the value of this environment variable and want to increase by 1. I am trying to do this in my gulp file:

```
gulp.task('incrementBuildId', function()
{
    process.env.BUILD_ID = buildId + 1;
});
```

However the value of environment variable isn't getting changed. Am I doing anything wrong here?
Is there any other way to have a global environment variable and keep changing it's value?

Comment: can you share your `.gitlab-ci.yml`, it should be in the root folder of your project.

Comment: I am not sure how would that help. I am not doing anything inside my .gitlab-ci.yml file apart from calling incrementBuildId as part of one of my stage.

Comment: The intention was to know how are you triggering the gulp task (npm), if your gulp-task is a phase inside gitlab-ci.yml then you could easily increment it.

Comment: Also, you should know, CI Environment variables can only be modified through the UI, you may increment it and use it in a pipeline trigger but when the next pipeline will trigger it will take the initial value. :)  It's a good read - here https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/

Comment: Ahh I see, so is there anything else I can do to set value globally from CI pipeline? So when next time pipeline gets triggered, the new value should get fetched.

Comment: please read the below answer.

Comment: if you got the answer you may accept/upvote

Answer (score 2):

As of now, there is no way to modify gitlab environment variable to persist. However, you could look for any `vault` or api-server to do the same.

**Option 1: (Recommended)**

For your case, if I'm not wrong you want to set the build ID as `last build ID +1` for that purpose gitlab allows a pipeline to commit  to a specific branch, so you could have the pipeline read a file which contains the last build ID and then set the current build ID as `last build ID+1` then commit it to branch and repeat the process for every build.

CI_COMMIT_SHA: is unique per commit
CI_PIPELINE_ID: is Unique per pipeline
CI_JOB_ID: is unique per Pipeline

So, You could use 
 - CI_PIPELINE_ID + CI_JOB_ID 
 - CI_COMMIT_SHA + CI_JOB_ID

This will produce unique values even if you run the same pipeline (CI) again and again.

**Option 2:**

However, I would recommend you give the build ID as the pipeline ID (known as CI_PIPELINE_ID) which is unique. example,

```
build_id = v1.0.${CI_PIPELINE_ID} #during build phase
#if current pipeline id = 3000, then build_id will be v1.0.3000
```

You may find the variables available with gitlab [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/). Some variables are unique like `CI_JOB_ID`, `CI_COMMIT_SHA`, `CI_PIPELINE_ID`  etc., (for gitlab v9.0+).

Comment: I think 2nd option will not be much useful for me as I don't have control on ID which is getting generated. I didn't get much how would 1st option work, did you mean to have a file in my project which specifies the value of BUILD_ID and I can keep changing that value as part of specific stage?

Comment: Let's say that there is a file in your project containing the `last build id` now in your pipeline you can read that file and increment it and `commit` it back to the branch such that next build will read the current incremented build id.

Comment: Hmm sounds like viable. I will give it a try

Comment: Some time has passed since this question was asked, but I'm facing a similar situation. The problem is, let's say that I use Option 1 and I increment a value of a file when the pipeline runs, then I commit+push this file during the pipeline. My pipeline fires, say, when I commit on the branch `master`. This causes my pipeline-commit (the one committed+pushed in the pipeline) to trigger a second pipeline, starting an infinite loop. One ends with [this situation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50955931/prevent-infinite-loop-with-gitlab-pipeline-and-git-pushing). How can one avoid it?

Comment: Should one push to a different branch from `master`?

Comment: Why are you not using the commit SHA reference or CI_JOB_ID?

Comment: I see you've asked a question on GitLab community as well https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-foss/-/issues/58567.

Comment: I've also added details to Option 1, please accept the answer if this solves your problem.